# Get Product list with attribute (news_from_date and news_to_date)Magento API

Tags: soap, soap-api-v2

I would like to get Product list with attributes (`news_from_date` and `news_to_date`) using `Magento API V2`.

I want to retrieve the product list within date-range that i define with attributes (`news_from_date` and `news_to_date`).

Comment: In Default Magento Product List API V2 provided following fields in response 

product_id
sku
name
set
type
category_ids
website_ids
If are you need custom attribute then customize default code.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento API V2 you need to add complex filter array like

```
 $params = array('complex_filter'=>
array(
    array('key'=>'created_at','value'=>array('key' =>'from','value' => '2012-07-05 01:01:01'))
));
```

As an example shows in dev docs of the api

https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Introduction+to+Magento+1.x+Module+Development#api_version_v2

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I've got it.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00");
$newtodate = $row->news_to_date;
$newfromdate = $row->news_from_date;

if (isset($newfromdate) and isset($newtodate) and $date >= $newfromdate and $date <= $newtodate) {
     $result[] = $row->product_id;
}
$complexFilter = array('complex_filter' =>
                           array(
                                 array(
                                   'key' => 'product_id', 
                                   'value' => array(
                                       'key' => 'in', 'value' => $result)
                                      )
                            )
                 );
```

And I used `catalogProductList` function to get the product list.